# Rolling regression for one period forward prediction

Tags: r

I am trying to create a series of one period forward predictions.  I am training my model on a rolling set of origins i.e., Macro[1:13] to predict Macro[14:14] Macro[1:12] to predict Macro[13:13] and so on all the way until Macro[1:8].

The below code gets me to my solution, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution and any other considerations.  Thanks!

```
Macro <- read.csv("C:/Macro.csv")
View(Macro)

Y <-Macro[1:13,2]
X <-Macro[1:13,3]
S1 <-Macro[1:13,4]
S2 <-Macro[1:13,5]
S3 <-Macro[1:13,6]

fit <- lm(Y ~ X + S1 + S2 + S3)

predict(fit, Macro[14:14,3:6])



Y <-Macro[1:12,2]
X <-Macro[1:12,3]
S1 <-Macro[1:12,4]
S2 <-Macro[1:12,5]
S3 <-Macro[1:12,6]

fit <- lm(Y ~ X + S1 + S2 + S3)

predict(fit, Macro[13:13,3:6])



Y <-Macro[1:11,2]
X <-Macro[1:11,3]
S1 <-Macro[1:11,4]
S2 <-Macro[1:11,5]
S3 <-Macro[1:11,6]

fit <- lm(Y ~ X + S1 + S2 + S3)

predict(fit, Macro[12:12,3:6])




Y <-Macro[1:10,2]
X <-Macro[1:10,3]
S1 <-Macro[1:10,4]
S2 <-Macro[1:10,5]
S3 <-Macro[1:10,6]

fit <- lm(Y ~ X + S1 + S2 + S3)

predict(fit, Macro[11:11,3:6])




Y <-Macro[1:9,2]
X <-Macro[1:9,3]
S1 <-Macro[1:9,4]
S2 <-Macro[1:9,5]
S3 <-Macro[1:9,6]

fit <- lm(Y ~ X + S1 + S2 + S3)

predict(fit, Macro[10:10,3:6])



Y <-Macro[1:8,2]
X <-Macro[1:8,3]
S1 <-Macro[1:8,4]
S2 <-Macro[1:8,5]
S3 <-Macro[1:8,6]

fit <- lm(Y ~ X + S1 + S2 + S3)

predict(fit, Macro[9:9,3:6])
```

Comment: hi @ZJAY can I ask why you are dooing such a prediction process?

Comment: Because I am dealing with very small amounts of data, and forecasting one period forward is my method of validating the model.  Any issues you can foresee?  Thanks.

Comment: ok i was just wondering if it was indeed for cross validation. In this case `caret` is the right tool to use.

Comment: Agreed: @agenis deserves the green tick here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the library `caret` which is capable to train multiple time series models with rolling window (with the option `timeslice`). From what i understood you want to have a training window that expands at each time of +1 and predict only the next observation (see the control parameters, for an illustration of the other options see [this image](http://topepo.github.io/caret/main_files/figure-html/Split_time-1.png)). So you just have to replace here by the name of your data.Frame and the variables in the formula:

```
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
mycontrol <- trainControl(method = "timeslice",
                              initialWindow = 8,
                              horizon = 1,
                              fixedWindow = FALSE, 
                          savePredictions = TRUE)
myfit <- train(unemploy ~ pce + pop + psavert,
                    data = head(economics, 15),
                    method = "lm",
                    trControl = mycontrol)
print(myfit$pred)
####       pred  obs rowIndex parameter  Resample
#### 1 2783.092 2877        9      none Training1
#### 2 2943.586 2709       10      none Training2
#### 3 2771.019 2740       11      none Training3
#### 4 2722.083 2938       12      none Training4
#### 5 2820.074 2883       13      none Training5
#### ...
```

You access the predictions by doing `myfit$pred$pred`. In addition to this it will also give you detailed information on the quality of each prediction, etc. The library `ggplot2` is only here for the example data.

Answer (score 0):

#### A more compact way (edited to fix a syntax error).

```
myfun <- function(model_len, dat, ...){
  dat <- data.frame(dat)
  names(dat) <- c("foo", "Y", "X", "S1", "S2", "S3")

  fit <- lm(Y ~ X + S1 + S2 + S3, data=dat[(1:model_len),])
  predict(fit, dat[(model_len + 1),])
}

sapply(8:13,  myfun, dat=Macro)
```

#### Other considerations

If this is time series data, linear regression might not be the best choice for modelling. If the residuals are either not Gaussian or not independent (not auto-correlated), then `lm()` can give answers that look convincing but are pretty far from useful.

Comment: This is time series data.  What would you suggest to use instead?  Thanks.

Comment: See @agenis 's answer above, and check out here for a choice of models. http://topepo.github.io/caret/bytag.html

Comment: Thanks - I used your following code below and got a 'incorrect number of dimensions error'                                Macro <- read.csv("C:/Macro.csv")
View(Macro)





myfun <- function(Macro, model_len){
  X <- Macro[1:model_len,2]
  Y <- Macro[1:model_len,3]
  S1 <- Macro[1:model_len,4]
  S2 <- Macro[1:model_len,5]
  S3 <- Macro[1:model_len,6]
  fit <- lm(Y ~ X + S1 + S2 + S3)
  predict(fit, Macro[model_len + 1,3:6])
}

sapply(Macro, myfun, model_len = 13:8)

Comment: Edited the above. As for which model might be more appropriate: it really depends how important it is to be right. Time series is a big subject; too big for me to comment in this space, especially with no data.